# Can't create a new desktop workspace?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, spaces

When I bring up the spaces option (by either pressing the F3 button or 4 finger swipe up on trackpad), the + button in the top right corner is no longer there and I can't create a new desktop space.

I am running mavericks 10.9.4 on a 2012 13" MacBook Pro.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The **+** button only appears if you move your mouse close to the location of the button, or hold down ⌥. Also note that you can have a maximum of 17 desktops, or 16 desktops and Dashboard, then the **+** button is no longer available.

Comment: The button does not appear anymore when I mouse over, that is the problem.  And I only have one desktop, so that is not the issue.  And holding down ⌥ does not work either.

Comment: Turns out the "+" button is now on the top left of the screen when you mouse over instead of the right.  Problem fixed technically, but still unsure why it is appearing on the wrong side.

Comment: That's so weird; this same thing happened to me (the + now appears on the left), but it was appearing on the right earlier today. I haven't done any updates on my machine--strange.

Answer (score 1):

Fun fact: If your desktop background is black (like mine is) you can almost see the "+" icon.  If you squint you can see its drop-shadow.  It was there all along, but I couldn't see it.

Nice work, Apple.

(I'm on Yosemite, if that matters.)

Comment: Grant Birchmeier is right, thanks for the answer, felt bad that your answer had been voted down. But I do not have sufficient reputation to upvote.

Comment: I didn't get downvoted, I just never got upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

the + button appears at top left if you switch your dock to the right.